# Session Variable lost in iFrame asp.net

Tags: asp.net, iframe, session-state

I have session variable that is created in EditPlaylist.aspx.  Edit.aspx is loading EditPlaylist.aspx in an iframe.

when loading sessions from EditPlaylist.aspx page they are null.

the session was not before I added the  EditPlaylist.aspx to an iFrame.  Is there a workaround for this?

Comment: What is in EditPlaylist.aspx or Edit.aspx? Where do you start the session? Are we psychic or what?

Comment: why is it loading in an iframe?? Why not editplaylist.aspx do all the work?

Answer (score -2):

If its running under IIS , how many workers processes do you have ?
if more than 1 - you have to share your session over all instances .